# How do I increase Tailwind CSS grid rows and columns?

Tags: tailwind-css

By default, Tailwind only allows up to [12 columns](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-template-columns#customizing-your-theme) and rows. How do I increase this?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `tailwind.config.js` to increase the maximum columns and rows to 24:

```js
theme: {
  extend: {
    gridColumn: {
      'span-13': 'span 13 / span 13',
      'span-14': 'span 14 / span 14',
      'span-15': 'span 15 / span 15',
      'span-16': 'span 16 / span 16',
      'span-17': 'span 17 / span 17',
      'span-18': 'span 18 / span 18',
      'span-19': 'span 19 / span 19',
      'span-20': 'span 20 / span 20',
      'span-21': 'span 21 / span 21',
      'span-22': 'span 22 / span 22',
      'span-23': 'span 23 / span 23',
      'span-24': 'span 24 / span 24',
    },
    gridRow: {
      'span-13': 'span 13 / span 13',
      'span-14': 'span 14 / span 14',
      'span-15': 'span 15 / span 15',
      'span-16': 'span 16 / span 16',
      'span-17': 'span 17 / span 17',
      'span-18': 'span 18 / span 18',
      'span-19': 'span 19 / span 19',
      'span-20': 'span 20 / span 20',
      'span-21': 'span 21 / span 21',
      'span-22': 'span 22 / span 22',
      'span-23': 'span 23 / span 23',
      'span-24': 'span 24 / span 24',
    },
    gridColumnStart: {
      '13': '13',
      '14': '14',
      '15': '15',
      '16': '16',
      '17': '17',
      '18': '18',
      '19': '19',
      '20': '20',
      '21': '21',
      '22': '22',
      '23': '23',
      '24': '24',
    },
    gridRowStart: {
      '13': '13',
      '14': '14',
      '15': '15',
      '16': '16',
      '17': '17',
      '18': '18',
      '19': '19',
      '20': '20',
      '21': '21',
      '22': '22',
      '23': '23',
      '24': '24',
    },
    gridColumnEnd: {
      '13': '13',
      '14': '14',
      '15': '15',
      '16': '16',
      '17': '17',
      '18': '18',
      '19': '19',
      '20': '20',
      '21': '21',
      '22': '22',
      '23': '23',
      '24': '24',
    },
    gridRowEnd: {
      '13': '13',
      '14': '14',
      '15': '15',
      '16': '16',
      '17': '17',
      '18': '18',
      '19': '19',
      '20': '20',
      '21': '21',
      '22': '22',
      '23': '23',
      '24': '24',
    },
    gridTemplateColumns: {
      '13': 'repeat(13, minmax(0, 1fr))',
      '14': 'repeat(14, minmax(0, 1fr))',
      '15': 'repeat(15, minmax(0, 1fr))',
      '16': 'repeat(16, minmax(0, 1fr))',
      '17': 'repeat(17, minmax(0, 1fr))',
      '18': 'repeat(18, minmax(0, 1fr))',
      '19': 'repeat(19, minmax(0, 1fr))',
      '20': 'repeat(20, minmax(0, 1fr))',
      '21': 'repeat(21, minmax(0, 1fr))',
      '22': 'repeat(22, minmax(0, 1fr))',
      '23': 'repeat(23, minmax(0, 1fr))',
      '24': 'repeat(24, minmax(0, 1fr))',
    },
    gridTemplateRows: {
      '13': 'repeat(13, minmax(0, 1fr))',
      '14': 'repeat(14, minmax(0, 1fr))',
      '15': 'repeat(15, minmax(0, 1fr))',
      '16': 'repeat(16, minmax(0, 1fr))',
      '17': 'repeat(17, minmax(0, 1fr))',
      '18': 'repeat(18, minmax(0, 1fr))',
      '19': 'repeat(19, minmax(0, 1fr))',
      '20': 'repeat(20, minmax(0, 1fr))',
      '21': 'repeat(21, minmax(0, 1fr))',
      '22': 'repeat(22, minmax(0, 1fr))',
      '23': 'repeat(23, minmax(0, 1fr))',
      '24': 'repeat(24, minmax(0, 1fr))',
    }
  },
},
```