# Tailwind increasing row-span past 6?

Tags: tailwind-css

I am trying to create a grid and I need an element to have a row span greater than 6, however, the tailwind documentation says that row-span-6 is the highest I can go. How do I resolve this?

This is my grid:

```
<div className="grid grid-cols-12 grid-rows-10 gap-4 h-screen">
    <div className="col-span-12 bg-black">1</div>
    <div className="col-span-3 row-span-5 row-start-2 bg-black">2</div>
    <div className="col-span-3 row-span-3 col-start-1 row-start-7 bg-black">5</div>
    <div className="col-span-12 col-start-1 row-start-10 bg-black">6</div>
    <div className="col-span-3 row-span-2 col-start-10 row-start-2 bg-black">7</div>
    <div className="col-span-3 row-span-2 col-start-10 row-start-4 bg-black">8</div>
    <div className="col-span-3 row-span-4 col-start-10 row-start-6 bg-black">9</div>
    <div className="col-span-6 row-span-8 text-white col-start-4 row-start-2 bg-black" >10</div>
</div>
```

And this is my tailwind.config.js: This was sourced from another post: [How do I increase Tailwind CSS grid rows and columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77163443/how-do-i-increase-tailwind-css-grid-rows-and-columns), but still has no results

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        'image' : "url('/img/BackgroundImage.png')",
      },
      gridColumn: {
        'span-13': 'span 13 / span 13',
        'span-14': 'span 14 / span 14',
        'span-15': 'span 15 / span 15',
        'span-16': 'span 16 / span 16',
        'span-17': 'span 17 / span 17',
        'span-18': 'span 18 / span 18',
        'span-19': 'span 19 / span 19',
        'span-20': 'span 20 / span 20',
        'span-21': 'span 21 / span 21',
        'span-22': 'span 22 / span 22',
        'span-23': 'span 23 / span 23',
        'span-24': 'span 24 / span 24',
      },
      gridRow: {
        'span-13': 'span 13 / span 13',
        'span-14': 'span 14 / span 14',
        'span-15': 'span 15 / span 15',
        'span-16': 'span 16 / span 16',
        'span-17': 'span 17 / span 17',
        'span-18': 'span 18 / span 18',
        'span-19': 'span 19 / span 19',
        'span-20': 'span 20 / span 20',
        'span-21': 'span 21 / span 21',
        'span-22': 'span 22 / span 22',
        'span-23': 'span 23 / span 23',
        'span-24': 'span 24 / span 24',
      },
      gridColumnStart: {
        '13': '13',
        '14': '14',
        '15': '15',
        '16': '16',
        '17': '17',
        '18': '18',
        '19': '19',
        '20': '20',
        '21': '21',
        '22': '22',
        '23': '23',
        '24': '24',
      },
      gridRowStart: {
        '13': '13',
        '14': '14',
        '15': '15',
        '16': '16',
        '17': '17',
        '18': '18',
        '19': '19',
        '20': '20',
        '21': '21',
        '22': '22',
        '23': '23',
        '24': '24',
      },
      gridColumnEnd: {
        '13': '13',
        '14': '14',
        '15': '15',
        '16': '16',
        '17': '17',
        '18': '18',
        '19': '19',
        '20': '20',
        '21': '21',
        '22': '22',
        '23': '23',
        '24': '24',
      },
      gridRowEnd: {
        '13': '13',
        '14': '14',
        '15': '15',
        '16': '16',
        '17': '17',
        '18': '18',
        '19': '19',
        '20': '20',
        '21': '21',
        '22': '22',
        '23': '23',
        '24': '24',
      },
      gridTemplateColumns: {
        '13': 'repeat(13, minmax(0, 1fr))',
        '14': 'repeat(14, minmax(0, 1fr))',
        '15': 'repeat(15, minmax(0, 1fr))',
        '16': 'repeat(16, minmax(0, 1fr))',
        '17': 'repeat(17, minmax(0, 1fr))',
        '18': 'repeat(18, minmax(0, 1fr))',
        '19': 'repeat(19, minmax(0, 1fr))',
        '20': 'repeat(20, minmax(0, 1fr))',
        '21': 'repeat(21, minmax(0, 1fr))',
        '22': 'repeat(22, minmax(0, 1fr))',
        '23': 'repeat(23, minmax(0, 1fr))',
        '24': 'repeat(24, minmax(0, 1fr))',
      },
      gridTemplateRows: {
        '13': 'repeat(13, minmax(0, 1fr))',
        '14': 'repeat(14, minmax(0, 1fr))',
        '15': 'repeat(15, minmax(0, 1fr))',
        '16': 'repeat(16, minmax(0, 1fr))',
        '17': 'repeat(17, minmax(0, 1fr))',
        '18': 'repeat(18, minmax(0, 1fr))',
        '19': 'repeat(19, minmax(0, 1fr))',
        '20': 'repeat(20, minmax(0, 1fr))',
        '21': 'repeat(21, minmax(0, 1fr))',
        '22': 'repeat(22, minmax(0, 1fr))',
        '23': 'repeat(23, minmax(0, 1fr))',
        '24': 'repeat(24, minmax(0, 1fr))',
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-row#customizing-your-theme):

> By default, Tailwind includes grid-row utilities for working with grids with up to 6 explicit rows. You can customize these values by editing `theme.gridRow`, `theme.extend.gridRow`, […] in your `tailwind.config.js` file.

You have already done this somewhat:

```js
gridRow: {
  'span-13': 'span 13 / span 13',
  'span-14': 'span 14 / span 14',
  'span-15': 'span 15 / span 15',
  'span-16': 'span 16 / span 16',
  'span-17': 'span 17 / span 17',
  'span-18': 'span 18 / span 18',
  'span-19': 'span 19 / span 19',
  'span-20': 'span 20 / span 20',
  'span-21': 'span 21 / span 21',
  'span-22': 'span 22 / span 22',
  'span-23': 'span 23 / span 23',
  'span-24': 'span 24 / span 24',
},
```

So to create a `row-span-8` class, we can add to this object like:

```js
gridRow: {
  'span-8': 'span 8/ span 8',
  // …
},
```

See in this live example:

```js
tailwind.config = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        'image': "url('/img/BackgroundImage.png')",
      },
      gridColumn: {
        'span-13': 'span 13 / span 13',
        'span-14': 'span 14 / span 14',
        'span-15': 'span 15 / span 15',
        'span-16': 'span 16 / span 16',
        'span-17': 'span 17 / span 17',
        'span-18': 'span 18 / span 18',
        'span-19': 'span 19 / span 19',
        'span-20': 'span 20 / span 20',
        'span-21': 'span 21 / span 21',
        'span-22': 'span 22 / span 22',
        'span-23': 'span 23 / span 23',
        'span-24': 'span 24 / span 24',
      },
      gridRow: {
        'span-8': 'span 8 / span 8',
        'span-13': 'span 13 / span 13',
        'span-14': 'span 14 / span 14',
        'span-15': 'span 15 / span 15',
        'span-16': 'span 16 / span 16',
        'span-17': 'span 17 / span 17',
        'span-18': 'span 18 / span 18',
        'span-19': 'span 19 / span 19',
        'span-20': 'span 20 / span 20',
        'span-21': 'span 21 / span 21',
        'span-22': 'span 22 / span 22',
        'span-23': 'span 23 / span 23',
        'span-24': 'span 24 / span 24',
      },
      gridColumnStart: {
        '13': '13',
        '14': '14',
        '15': '15',
        '16': '16',
        '17': '17',
        '18': '18',
        '19': '19',
        '20': '20',
        '21': '21',
        '22': '22',
        '23': '23',
        '24': '24',
      },
      gridRowStart: {
        '13': '13',
        '14': '14',
        '15': '15',
        '16': '16',
        '17': '17',
        '18': '18',
        '19': '19',
        '20': '20',
        '21': '21',
        '22': '22',
        '23': '23',
        '24': '24',
      },
      gridColumnEnd: {
        '13': '13',
        '14': '14',
        '15': '15',
        '16': '16',
        '17': '17',
        '18': '18',
        '19': '19',
        '20': '20',
        '21': '21',
        '22': '22',
        '23': '23',
        '24': '24',
      },
      gridRowEnd: {
        '13': '13',
        '14': '14',
        '15': '15',
        '16': '16',
        '17': '17',
        '18': '18',
        '19': '19',
        '20': '20',
        '21': '21',
        '22': '22',
        '23': '23',
        '24': '24',
      },
      gridTemplateColumns: {
        '13': 'repeat(13, minmax(0, 1fr))',
        '14': 'repeat(14, minmax(0, 1fr))',
        '15': 'repeat(15, minmax(0, 1fr))',
        '16': 'repeat(16, minmax(0, 1fr))',
        '17': 'repeat(17, minmax(0, 1fr))',
        '18': 'repeat(18, minmax(0, 1fr))',
        '19': 'repeat(19, minmax(0, 1fr))',
        '20': 'repeat(20, minmax(0, 1fr))',
        '21': 'repeat(21, minmax(0, 1fr))',
        '22': 'repeat(22, minmax(0, 1fr))',
        '23': 'repeat(23, minmax(0, 1fr))',
        '24': 'repeat(24, minmax(0, 1fr))',
      },
      gridTemplateRows: {
        '13': 'repeat(13, minmax(0, 1fr))',
        '14': 'repeat(14, minmax(0, 1fr))',
        '15': 'repeat(15, minmax(0, 1fr))',
        '16': 'repeat(16, minmax(0, 1fr))',
        '17': 'repeat(17, minmax(0, 1fr))',
        '18': 'repeat(18, minmax(0, 1fr))',
        '19': 'repeat(19, minmax(0, 1fr))',
        '20': 'repeat(20, minmax(0, 1fr))',
        '21': 'repeat(21, minmax(0, 1fr))',
        '22': 'repeat(22, minmax(0, 1fr))',
        '23': 'repeat(23, minmax(0, 1fr))',
        '24': 'repeat(24, minmax(0, 1fr))',
      }
    },
  },
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

<div class="grid grid-cols-12 grid-rows-10 gap-4 h-screen">
  <div class="col-span-12 bg-black">1</div>
  <div class="col-span-3 row-span-5 row-start-2 bg-black">2</div>
  <div class="col-span-3 row-span-3 col-start-1 row-start-7 bg-black">5</div>
  <div class="col-span-12 col-start-1 row-start-10 bg-black">6</div>
  <div class="col-span-3 row-span-2 col-start-10 row-start-2 bg-black">7</div>
  <div class="col-span-3 row-span-2 col-start-10 row-start-4 bg-black">8</div>
  <div class="col-span-3 row-span-4 col-start-10 row-start-6 bg-black">9</div>
  <div class="col-span-6 row-span-8 text-white col-start-4 row-start-2 bg-black">10</div>
</div>
```